# Extracting meta data from raw images (DSLR camera)

Tags: command-line, photography, photo-management

I am searching for a tool, that extracts meta data out of raw images produced by a digital SLR (in my case Canon EOS 550D).

The photos can be converted by a recent version of ufraw ([here](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ppa) is the PPA for that).

With my compact camera I simply use exif, which only works on jpg and does not work with raw images.

Any hints?

Comment: Are you looking for a commandline tool, or a GUI tool?

Comment: It has to be a command-line tool. I want to use the output to rename the files by date.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information you posted in your comment about needing a command line tool.

Comment: Would this be better for superuser.com ?

Comment: ufraw on the command line has an --exif switch which tells it to copy the exif data from your raw file the output file

Comment: related post: [How to get/edit EXIF meta-data of multiple images?](http://askubuntu.com/q/101688/62483)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the description of the package `exifprobe`:

> Exifprobe reads image files produced
> by digital cameras (including several
> so-called "raw" file formats) and
> reports the structure of the files and
> the auxiliary data and metadata
> contained within them. In addition to
> TIFF, JPEG, and EXIF, the program
> understands several formats which may
> contain "raw" camera data, including
> MRW, CIFF/CRW, JP2/JPEG2000, RAF, and
> X3F, as well as most most TIFF-derived
> "raw" formats, including DNG, ORF,
> CR2, NEF, K25/KDC/DCR, and PEF.
>
> [http://www.virtual-cafe.com/~dhh/tools.d/exifprobe.d/exifprobe.html](http://www.virtual-cafe.com/%7Edhh/tools.d/exifprobe.d/exifprobe.html)

Does that work?

Comment: I will give it a try. Since my camera model does not seem to be support, I will have to check it at home. Thanks!

Comment: The virtual-cafe link is dead, but I found a fork on github that is working on macOS, assume it works on ubuntu: https://github.com/hfiguiere/exifprobe

Answer (score 2):

I would use exiv2 tool this is the same library as ufraw/darktable uses for accessing exif data in raw images.. http://www.exiv2.org/
which also does support some MakerNotes from manufactors such as Nikon/Canon.
With exiv2 it also possible to look at some advanced technical data about image. For example

```bsh
exiv2 -P nxytv your_raw_file
```

will output all tags as
`tag hex code` `tag name` `tag data type` `tag plain data` `tag interpreted data`

which contains, for example, ColorMatrix and CameraCalibration values.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment I get it that what you ultimately want to do is renaming the file based on the date. If that's the only reason why you want to use a commandline tool instead of a GUI, you could try **phatch** (in the repositories) instead of doing the EXIF extraction/file renaming yourself.

Phatch allows to batch process images (i.e. perform a set of actions on every image in a folder for example). One of the possible actions is *rename* and you can use Variables like `<Exif_Image_DateTime>` to rename it based on the EXIF data. Once you defined and saved your list of actions, you can also use phatch from the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd consider writing a little Python script to do this, pulling in [`pyexiv2`](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/). It's extremely easy to use:

```
>>> metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata('test.jpg')
>>> metadata.read()
>>> metadata.exif_keys
['Exif.Image.ImageDescription',
 'Exif.Image.XResolution',
 'Exif.Image.YResolution',
 'Exif.Image.ResolutionUnit',
 'Exif.Image.Software',
 'Exif.Image.DateTime',
 'Exif.Image.Artist',
 'Exif.Image.Copyright',
 'Exif.Image.ExifTag',
 'Exif.Photo.Flash',
 'Exif.Photo.PixelXDimension',
 'Exif.Photo.PixelYDimension']
>>> metadata['Exif.Image.DateTime'].value
datetime.datetime(2004, 7, 13, 21, 23, 44)
```

**Note:** Different cameras use different fields for dates. Check first to see what keys are available.

It should support raw images. I know it does for the NEF raw files my Nikon creates.

If it doesn't, do you have JPEG versions too with similar names (ie different extensions)? Even if it *can* parse your RAW files, it might be worth ticking through the JPEGs for its EXIF data because it'll likely be a bit faster.

**Tip:** You can use the Python shell instead of having to write a "proper" Python script. This is good for testing things out but if you want something you can use over and over again, you probably want to write a script.

Comment: Thanks, but I am pretty bad in Python.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite answer for fussing with EXIF data is [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). It's portable, free, open, written in Perl, and can be used as a Perl module for those so inclined.

It even works on Windows.

Comment: Oh, if that works, it would be great.