# How do I resolve date range events?

Tags: shotwell, events

Shotwell has grouped a large number of images in a "date range" event. I do not know when and how this happened; the images may have been group this way for a year or so. All new images a event tagged correctly.

At any rate: is there a way to move the images to their right event, based on their dates?

Dates (both EXIF and file system dates) seem to be correct.

I use Shotwell version 0.12.3 and has been using it for a couple of years. It works fine, otherwise.

Per.

Answer (score 2):

Shotwell defines Events as '[A group of photos that were taken at approximately the same time.](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/event.html)' This is a grey area, and things like batches of scanned images, multiple photo shoots with multiple imports the same day, or sets of photos taken around midnight, can leave you with an event structure that you might not prefer.

If your goal is to have Shotwell sort photos **strictly by individual dates**, then this is a long-standing bug report/feature request ([#2747](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/2747)). Disabling events entirely and using date only is another closely related request ([#2665](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/2665)).

Questions that are bug reports (and feature requests are a subset of bug reports) are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu so your [question may be closed](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).

If you want to manually sort the images in question, creating events and moving groups of images in to each event, Shotwell's [help page](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/event.html) describes how. I'll summarize here but it's best to read that entire page.

- To **rename** an event select Events -> Rename Event or double-click it and type.
- To **move** photos between events, drag any photo to the sidebar and drop it on an event.
- To **create** a new event select Events -> New Event

If you find that any of the photos have the wrong date/time that's [easy to adjust too](https://askubuntu.com/a/101695/12864).